# css animations moves element position

Tags: css, animation, css-position, positioning

I have this problem with my CSS animation. I have an element position absolute centered in the middle of the page and when I put the animation on, it moves to the right and when the animation is finished it moves back to the middle of the page. Here's the code:

```
@keyframes motto
 from
  opacity: 0
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0)
 to
  opacity: 1
  transform: none

#home
 .motto
  position: absolute
  top: 50%
  left: 50%
  margin-right: -50%
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
  animation-name: motto
  animation-duration: 2s
  h1
   margin: 0
   font-size: 42px
   font-weight: 100
   opacity: .5
   -webkit-animation-duration: 2s
```

Thx in advance!

```css
     @keyframes motto {
       from {
         opacity: 0;
         transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
       }
       to {
         opacity: 1;
         transform: none;
       }
    }
    .motto {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-right: -50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      animation-name: motto;
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }
    .motto h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 42px;
      font-weight: 100;
      opacity: .5
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
      }
```

```html
<div class="motto"><h1>css <span>animation</span></h1></div>
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You told us what happens but not what you want to happen.

Comment: I want the animation fade in down in the middle of the page. Now it fades in down on the right side and when the animation ends, the text it moves back in the middle.

Comment: Can you convert your code into a working snippet?

Comment: Yes, just a second.

Comment: Not sure if this will work, since I havent seen the code in action, but just off the top of my head perhaps use the `transform-origin`parameter. That sets the anchor point of the animation

Comment: I added a snippet, thx for help.

Comment: @DanielZaharia that's not a snippet, in the editor, look for an icon of a sheet of paper with "< >". Use that.

Comment: Don't worry, I did the snippet for him, however it needs to be "peer reviewed". Also solved the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following line in the CSS of `.motto` :

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;`

This sets the element to display as it is in the final frame of the animation.

```css
@keyframes motto {
       from {
         opacity: 0;
         transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
       }
       to {
         opacity: 1;
         transform: none;
       }
    }
    .motto {
      position: absolute;
      width: 400px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-left: -200px;
      animation-name: motto;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    .motto h1 {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 42px;
      font-weight: 100;
      opacity: .5;
      text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<div class="motto"><h1>css <span>animation</span></h1></div>
```

Comment: yes, but it still remains to the right, I want it to the middle :)

Comment: edited my answer. At the moment the animation starts in the center vertically and moves down 100px. If you wish for it to end at 50%, I can make that change for you as well

Comment: Also you had some extra code that didn't do anything, I removed that lol

Comment: Thx bro, that's awesome. But the thing is, I have a big large text and is responsive and when I go on mobile it fades to the left now :))

Comment: Will you have other elements on the page? Behind it or beneath it?

Comment: Yes, is a parallax page, and the text in the middle, but its position absolute, does other elements have to do anything with that?

Comment: Well, I have the nav bar on the top of the page and the background beneath.

Comment: I can't do all of this for you, however I can tell you that I would suggest you should create a container, within which you put this animation, and above or below, put the rest of your content so that it does not clash with this animation. I wouldn't use `position: absolute` for what you are trying to do. Good luck!