# Absolutely positioned element moves after animation completes

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

it's been awhile. Anyway, having some trouble getting an absolutely positioned element to stay center *while* animating. What's more is I'm seeing the element "shift" after the animation is complete and I have no idea why. Closest issue I found was [css animations moves element position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208495/css-animations-moves-element-position) but that didn't solve for this common use case.

Debugging the animation frames, we can see the following:

During animation
[image: during animation]

After animation
[image: after animation]

Yuck! Playing with positioning didn't work, but `animation-fill-mode` did something; however, I noticed `translate` has no effect on the positioned element during animation or when `animation-fill-mode` is set to `forwards` or `both`. Why? The side effect is when the animation completes the element's position will not be recalculated so no repaint.

Example:

```html
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

and the CSS using `animate.css` to make life easy:

```css
.alert {
  min-width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  /* animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/atomicpages/pen/yrymVY?editors=1100

Goals:

1. Center aligned
2. Element is *at least* `500px`
3. Element doesn't move after animation frame completes

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: No, we're operating within the constraints provided in the code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom fadeInDown without `animate.css` because it is using `transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0)` in fadeIndown

```css
.alert {
  width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position:absolute;
}

@keyframes fadeInDown{
  from{
    opacity:0;
  }
  to{
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown{
  from{
    opacity:0;
  }
  to{
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> You should check in on some of those fields below.
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Mamma Mia! I should have looked at `animate.css`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing transform: translateX, after the animation, the element stays where it is, and change it to left: 0;

```
.alert {
  min-width: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation-name: fadeInDown;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the element being centered

Comment: Isn't it? I'm seeing the element as centered, it is neither to the left nor to the right after the animation? Please explain further about it being centered

Comment: Provide an example

Comment: `left: 30%` doesn't keep the element centered as the viewport size changes

Comment: would you prefer aligning center the text instead?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the built-in `fadeInDown` also use `transform` for its animation, hence resets/override your initial value, and restore it after, unless you use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, which will keep it 50% off the left edge all the time.

*And do note, preset `transform` "values", like `translateX` doesn't persist when another "value" is added to the "property", all existing values gets overwritten.*

Original CSS

```
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

For yours to work you need to override the built-in one, adding your `translateX` value to it, and it will behave.

*And if you do, there is a prefixed `@keyframes` rule as well, which also need to be updated.*

New CSS

```
@keyframes fadeInDown {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, -100%, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -100%, 0);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

---

As a side note:

With the provided setting it will always take full width and centering it would have no effect, unless you also gave it a `max-width` somewhere else.